# Showing only one application in windows?

Tags: productivity

Sometimes I want to minimize distractions on the screen. It is easy for some applications, browsers and pdf readers usually have a fullscreen option.

Is there a way/software to only show one application and hide everything else (including taskbar) for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some utilities by [Skrommel](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/) :

[TransOther](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/TransOther/TransOther.exe)

> Make all windows but the active one
>   transparent.
>
> Features:
>
> - User defined transparency level.
> - Can ignore always ontop windows.
> - Won't make parent windows transparent while children is active.

[Ghoster](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/Ghoster/Ghoster.exe)

> Dims all windows except the active
>   one.
>
> Features:
>
> - Place a transparent image across the screen.
> - Highly configurable.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on taskbar, properties, mark the automatically hide taskbar option. It will hide it until you carry the mouse cursor again to that area. You can set a different place for the taskbar, does not have to be in the lower area.  For a fast minimizing of all windows, you can right click on taskbar, then hit 'Show desktop'.